# How to transform xsl:result-document to multiple files using Saxon java api?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

There is a .xsl file with xsl:result-document thaht has to generate a multiple html files. How this xsl can be processed using the saxon s9api?

This is what I used to try to transform the xsl file.

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltTransformer transformer = compiler. compile(new StreamSource(new File(xlsFilePath))).load();
    XdmNode source = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFilePath)));
    transformer.setInitialContextNode(source);
    transformer.transform();
```

But I received:

> IllegalStateException: No destination has been supplied

Reading the documentation I have to specify the destionation if I want overwrite it, but in my case this is specified in href of the xsl:result-document.

So how can use the saxon java s9api to transform this xsl file for example?

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="book">
  <xsl:result-document href="book{position()}.html" method="html">
   <html>
    <head>
     <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body><xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/></body>
   </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't see how `xsl:template match="/"` with `xsl:for-each select="book"` would process more than the root element but in any case the transformation produces a primary result you need to handle I think, even if that is only an empty sequence in your case so try setting `transformer.setDestination(new XdmDestination())`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, transformer.setDestination(new XdmDestination()) was the solution!